# How to COUNT co-tags from a tag_map table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, select, group-by, mariadb-10.5

I have a simple tag_map table

```
CREATE TABLE TagMap
(
TagID mediumint(7) unsigned,
ArticleID int(11) unsigned,
FOREIGN KEY(TagID) REFERENCES Tags(TagID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(ArticleID) REFERENCES Articles(ArticleID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY(TagID,ArticleID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=1
```

I get the co-tags (tags, which appear along with a specific tag):

```
SELECT TagID AS TagID2,COUNT(*) FROM TagMap WHERE ArticleID IN(
SELECT ArticleID FROM TagMap WHERE TagID=1 // This is TagID1
) 
GROUP BY TagID
```

How can I do this query for all tags to get

```
TagID1,TagID2,COUNT(*)
```

The table is huge (10-50M rows) and each article has tens of tags. Thus, performance is critical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.TagID AS TagID1
    ,t2.TagID AS TagID2
    ,COUNT(1)
FROM TagMap AS t1
JOIN TagMap AS t2 ON t1.ArticleID = t2.ArticleID AND t1.TagID <> t2.TagID
GROUP BY t1.TagID, t2.TagID
```

UPDATED: index on ArticleID may help to improve query performance

Comment: Terminology for the technique:  "self-join".

Comment: Depending on the requirements, the output could be cut in half.  Currently it has [1,2,count] _and_ [2,1,count].  Change `<>` to `<`.

Comment: A "covering" index on `(ArticleID, TagID)` will further help performance.  (Instead of just `(ArticleID)`.)

Comment: @RickJames TagID is a part of the clustered index, index on ArticleID will include this column anyway